# Change the color of Lightning-input label

Tags: lightning-web-components, css, lightninginput, label

I have below code for input text

```
 <lightning-input label="Email" class="textInput" value={rec.Name} onchange={handleNameChange}></lightning-input>
```

Here I want to change the color of the label. I have tried it like this. But not working.

```
.textInput {
    color: black;
    font-weight: bold;
 }
```

When I see the inspect element it looks like:
[image]

How should I write the css?

Answer (score 6):

On the assumption you are talking LWC rather than Aura (since you reference "lightning-input" rather than "lightning:input"), LWC specifically restricts the parent from messing with the child component's presentation via the use of [Shadow DOM](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.create_dom).

As per the lightning-input [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-input/documentation), there are no exposed means to apply the styling you wish to apply. The only way to apply any form of styling is via the "variant" attribute.

Comment: When I add the color via the inspect element it works. And there it is under .slds-scope .slds-form-element__label {

Comment: I have updated the question with the image

Comment: Using the inspector works because you are accessing the shadow DOM content directly. You cannot do it programmatically in the LWC framework. See my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Try this in CSS file

```
.textInput{
     -webkit-text-fill-color: black;
}
```

It worked for me!!

Comment: +1 While this works here, but it will not work for all users as it is not standardized yet, [refer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-text-fill-color)

Answer (score 1):

You just need to set the variant to hit the default label

```
<lightning-input id="input-FirstName" type="text" variant="label-hidden"></lightning-input>
```

You can add a label using html
*First Name

Answer (score 1):

Try this
`lightning-input style="-webkit-text-fill-color:black"`

Comment: This is a duplicate of an existing answer, but with less information.

Comment: It's the easiest answer to implement, @DerekF

Answer (score 0):

```
<p class="l-text"> Email </P><lightning-input variant="label-hidden"value={rec.Name} onchange={handleNameChange}></lightning-input>
```

.l-text{
color: blue;
}

try this.

Comment: This does not work.

Answer (score 0):

You can load a special styling component in the main component .JS file

```
export default class ContainerMain extends LightningElement {
     connectedCallback() {
        // Get Styles
        Promise.all([
            loadStyle(this, Styles + '/Style.css')
        ])
    }
}
```

In your Style.css insert this

```
c-my-component-name .class-name{
    color: #5D6570;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 600;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Update your CSS file as:

```
.THIS .textInput{
    color: Black;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Also, input text as, `<lightning:input label="Email" class="textInput" value={!rec.Name} onchange={!c.handleNameChange}></lightning:input>`

Comment: Given the use of "lightning-input" I would suggest this is in the context of LWC rather than Aura, in which case the approach you suggest will not work.

Comment: Hi Rashmi, Yes I am working on LWC